# How to hide formula results until conditions are met

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am completely new to making spreadsheets with Excel and even more dumb when making formulas. I have come to surprise myself how much I have learned, but now I am stumped and could really use some help and hope I explain this clear enough.

- On my spreadsheet I have (A-I) columns.
- Column E is entered data (in this case # of loads I ordered for that
  day).
- Column G is entered data (for how many loads were rejected (not
  picked up)).
- Column H is entered data (for how many loads are picked up).
- Column I is for how many loads are left.

Now with that description my formula is as follows in column I:

- Row 8 is where my data starts `(=E8-G8-H8)` this gives me my total in
  column I.
- On I9 this is my formula `(=I8+E9-G9-H9)`

This works like I want it to but my problem is that it shows my last result all the way down the column. I want to hide those results until data is entered in column E.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with the [IF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php) function.

The format is

```
=IF(CONDITION, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse)
```

So in your case, it may work to do:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($E9),(I8+E9-G9-H9),"")
```

`ISBLANK()` in excel is a built in function to check for what it states.
`$` is included so if you move over to another column, it still reflects column `E`.  However, don't do that on the number, as that would always reference that number only, rather than following down to `E10`, for example, if you copy the formula down the row.

Comment: actually I have one more question..f5 I have the starting date.. I put a formula in starting in b8 to automatically fill in the rest of the dates down the spreadsheet.. when I delete the date in f5 I would like it to also not show results till f5 is entered.. normal formula for b8 is (=f5) then b9 is (=b8+1)

Comment: You could do the same thing as above, if I understand correctly.  Give it a shot to try out what you learned  here :)

Comment: yeah I tried before I commented.. what does (" ") do? or represent?

Comment: Updated for a better way, that was a lazy way to check if a cell had no contents.  However, there is a built in that is probably better `ISBLANK(E9)`.  Careful, " " would check for a space, "" checks for nothing - `ISBLANK()` is more clear.

Comment: Lol well lazy or not that formula worked for that task so it works for me.. but I have tried a few different ways for the date and no luck.. so F5 is the header date.. B8 is the start of the data.. I put in B8 (=F5) then B9 I put (=B8+1) now with what you have tried to explain to me I tried putting in B8 (=IF($F5<>" ",(=F5),") this obviously is not working..

Comment: Looks like you are putting a space and only one double quote at the end. Try: `=IF(ISBLANK(F5),F5,"")`.  Don't think you need the equals before F5, either.

Comment: That one didn't work..

Comment: That's a separate question, and it is frowned upon to have extended comments.  You would need it in the results cell.  Probably with `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(F5),ISBLANK(E9)),(I8+E9-G9-H9),"")` or some variant.  Do some more research and ask a new question if you need.