# How to hide formula results in a cell until conditions are met - percentage discount

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

My question relates to this post, but with different formula criteria: [How to hide formula results until conditions are met](https://superuser.com/questions/687088/how-to-hide-formula-results-until-conditions-are-met).

Here's the setup for a spreadsheet to calculate the percentage discount for various staff based on their hourly rates:

- Row D = regular $ rate for staffperson
- Row E = discounted $ rate for staffperson
- Row F = percentage % discount for staffperson

I would like to calculate the percentage difference in row F (I have the formula set up there) but I do not want anything to appear in the Row F's cells unless a discounted rate is entered in a Row E cell for a specific staffperson.  Currently, the way I have it set up, I always have values entered in the Row D cells since the regular rates do not change, but depending on the agreement with a client, I will often modify the discounted rate cells in Row E to reflect different discounted rates.  I would only like to see the percentage discount in a Row F cell if a value were entered in Row E for certain staff.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try to adapt the formula criteria in that question?  I would argue that this question is a near exact duplicate of that one.

Comment: I tried but the content in Row F would not appear when a value was input in Row E, which is kind of the opposite of what I'd like to accomplish.  I'm not certain how to tweak the formula so that a value appears in Row F if and only if a rate is entered in Row E.  Thanks.

Comment: @Byron is right. This is nearly an exact duplicate. Share the formula you are trying to use so we can see if you are using the proper syntax and help you get it to work. Also, is automatic calculation turned on? If not, it won't give you results in `F` unless you press F9.

Comment: Here's a sample of the formula, which I have placed in cell F24: =IF(ISBLANK($E24),((D24-E24)/D24),"").  When I add a value in E24, which represents the staffperson's discounted rate, cell F24 is blank.  When there is no value in E24, I see "100%" in F24.  I'd like to opposite effect to apply, where I would see the percentage discount to show up in F24 when I enter a value in E24.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your current formula, you flipped the "if true" and "if false" parameters.

I would use:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E1),"",(D1-E1)/D1)
```

This will display blank when E1 is blank, the % discount if it is not. If you want to prevent error displays (if D1 is blank, for example):

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(E1),"",(D1-E1)/D1),"")
```

You can also enter a different string between the last two " marks if you want it to say something like "Error - check standard and discount rates."

Comment: @MarcNatale If this answer worked for you, please consider marking it as accepted by clicked the check mark by the vote arrows. This lets other people know that this is the solution. Thanks.